# Logging T-SNE training?

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

We can log the training of libraries such as `gensim` using

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This doesn't work when running of T-SNE (from `sklearn.manifold`). Since this can take a long time, logging of some form would be nice. I have looked through the docs, but cannot seem to find another way to log the training of this. Is there a way to log this, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that sklearn [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/eaf0a044fdc084ebeeb9bbfbcf42e6df2b1491bb/sklearn/manifold/_t_sne.py#L472) don't have any logging. The [contributing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html) guide don't have any standard approach for this.

However you can use the *verbose* flag to get more information about what the class is doing.

If you use the flag like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1) # note the verbose flag

X_embedded = tsne.fit_transform(X)
X_embedded.shape(4, 2)
```

The output will be

```sh
[t-SNE] Computing 3 nearest neighbors...
[t-SNE] Indexed 4 samples in 0.000s...
[t-SNE] Computed neighbors for 4 samples in 0.000s...
[t-SNE] Computed conditional probabilities for sample 4 / 4
[t-SNE] Mean sigma: 1125899906842624.000000
[t-SNE] KL divergence after 250 iterations with early exaggeration: 31.763723
[t-SNE] KL divergence after 650 iterations: 0.048727
```

That code is adapted from [sklearn TSNE code example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html).

Note that output is the standard output, not a file of something like that. All messages from *verbose* flag is written using the *print* function.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed some kind of output.